# ReactJS componentDidMount fetch unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've just started to learn React and I am trying to perform some test also just to get around it.

I am playing with API and my componentDidMount uses feth call. How to simulate returning data from fetch when componentDidMount is executed or component is created? Basically **I just want to simulate fake call and then check if state was populated with this data.** 
I know than with Jasmine when testing Angular component you can do something like spyOn().thenReturn()  how can I achieve that?

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { CardList } from './components/card-list/card-list.component';
import { Search } from './components/search/search.component';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pokemons: [],
      searchField: ''
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=10')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res =>
        Promise.all(
          res.results.map(
            element => fetch(element.url)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(pokemon => { return { id: pokemon.id, name: pokemon.name, img: pokemon.sprites.front_default } })
          )
        )
      ).then(pokemons => this.setState({ pokemons }));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CardList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```